# Issue with nls model specification in R (singular gradient error)

Tags: r, nls

I am trying to fit a non-linear model using `nls` in R, however, I can't seem to get the model specification correct. Any advice on how to correct the model, would be much appreciated. A minimal example below.

```
# Import dummy data 
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guysutton/nls_singular_repo/main/data2.csv")
head(data)
```

I think the specification of the fixed effects is what is causing the issue. I am not experienced with fitting 'nls' and picking starting values, as several other StackOverflow posts have indicated that the error I am getting could be because of poor starting values. I have tried starting pH(1:3, in increments of 0.1).

```
# Fit NLS model 
mod <- stats::nls(
  # Response variable
  y ~
    # Predictors 
     ( (x1 + x2) / (-0.6258*pH^4+11.847*pH^3-79.884*pH^2+230.97*(pH)-242.64) ),
  start = list(pH = 1),
  control = nls.control(maxiter = 1000),
  data = data
)
```

> Error in nls(y ~ ((x1 + x2)/(-0.6258 * pH^4 + 11.847 * pH^3 - 79.884 *  :
> singular gradient

However, when I take the fixed effect expression and manually input values for the first row of data, I get the correct value.

```
# This produces the correct value for the first row of data when I sub in the values 
(x1 + x2) / (-0.6258*pH^4+11.847*pH^3-79.884*pH^2+230.97*(pH)-242.64)
(1.50 + 0.45) / (-0.6258*4.41^4+11.847*4.41^3-79.884*4.41^2+230.97*(4.41)-242.64)
```

> [1] 1.132759

Any advice on what might be causing my issue, and how to potentially solve this issue, would be much appreciated.

Comment: pH is only defined in [0,14]. Your denominator can become zero in this interval: `curve(-0.6258*x^4+11.847*x^3-79.884*x^2+230.97*(x)-242.64, from = 0, to = 14); abline(0,0)` This model sucks (unless you constrain pH to a specific interval where values of the denominator are never zero).

Comment: The point of `nls` is to find the coefficients in your model, but you don't have any coefficients to find. You are presupposing them; the numbers -0.6258, 11.847, -79.884, 230.97, and -242.64 are typically what you would use `nls` to find. If you already have these numbers, then you already have your model.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (as pointed out in the comments) is that you are trying to determine the coefficients for your model with `nls`. The way you currently have the model set up, you are trying to predict a single pH value that describes all the variability in y given x1 and x2. I think what you really want to to determine the coefficients for your input pH values that give the best model. Maybe something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mod <- stats::nls(
  # Response variable
  y ~
    # Predictors 
     ( (x1 + x2) /(k*pH + k2*pH^2 + k3*pH^3 + k4*pH^4) ),
  start = list(k = 10, k2 = 1, k3 = 0.3, k4 = 0.03),
  control = nls.control(maxiter = 1000, tol = 1e-3, minFactor = 1e-5),
  data = data
)

summary(mod)
#> 
#> Formula: y ~ ((x1 + x2)/(k * pH + k2 * pH^2 + k3 * pH^3 + k4 * pH^4))
#> 
#> Parameters:
#>      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> k  -113.65175    4.31320  -26.35   <2e-16 ***
#> k2   82.57272    3.20163   25.79   <2e-16 ***
#> k3  -19.84041    0.78430  -25.30   <2e-16 ***
#> k4    1.58837    0.06349   25.02   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.6587 on 5076 degrees of freedom
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 0.0007377

data|>
  mutate(mod = predict(mod)) |>
  ggplot(aes(y, mod))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_log10()+
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Also, it looks like you are doing some kind of expansion with the pH in the bottom, maybe because pH is log transformed [H+]. I'm not totally sure what you are trying to model, but there is probably a better function for the denominator.